# What does this lshw output mean?

Tags: ram

I am trying to figure out how many ram slots I have so I can buy a new ram for my laptop.

I ran

```
sudo lshw -C memory -short
```

And this is its ouput

```
H/W path         Device     Class          Description
======================================================
/0/3                        memory         4GiB System Memory
/0/3/0                      memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MH
/0/3/1                      memory         [empty]
/0/7                        memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/8                        memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/9                        memory         3MiB L3 cache
/0/b                        memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/100/1f.2                 memory         Memory controller
```

Comment: Do `sudo lshw -C memory` and it'll tell you how many slots, and what's in each slot currently. Also check `free -h`. You probably have two slots in your laptop. Go to https://www.crucial.com to best determine what memory to buy. Best to have two equal size/spec SODIMMs to take advantage of memory interleaving.

Comment: @heynnema turns out I sadly only have one. My laptop is x270 and the ram is quite old, it is 4 gb because it was given to us by our university.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/0/3                        memory         4GiB System Memory
/0/3/0                      memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MH
/0/3/1                      memory         [empty]
```

The first line of `/0/3` is the group of RAM `4GiB System Memory` total in the system. If you add another RAM module that number will change.  It shows one slot available in the `/0/3` group (one occupied in `/0/3/0` and one available in `/0/3/1`).  However, without physically checking it is hard to tell.  Some laptops were made with the connector for the RAM, but the slot wasn't soldered to the board.

You can use `inxi` to determine the max amount of RAM and slots.

Example:

```
sudo inxi -mx
Memory:
  RAM: total: 23.40 GiB used: 2.49 GiB (10.6%) 
  Array-1: capacity: 32 GiB note: est. slots: 4 EC: None 
  max module size: 8 GiB note: est. 
  Device-1: A0 size: 4 GiB speed: 1333 MT/s type: Unknown 
  Device-2: A1 size: 4 GiB speed: 1333 MT/s type: Unknown 
  Device-3: A2 size: 8 GiB speed: 1333 MT/s type: Unknown 
  Device-4: A3 size: 8 GiB speed: 1333 MT/s type: Unknown
```

Above we can see the maximum this board will take is 32GiB or 4 x 8GiB (max module size which means a 16GiB possibly will not work since it states `est` or estimated).

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you say there's one available and one empty. What `4GiB System Memory` does reffer to? Or `0/3` specifically?

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø That is the total that is in the system right now.  I updated the answer.

Comment: How many physical RAM slots do you have on your motherboard... 4 or 8?

Comment: @heynnema 4.  `Array-1: capacity: 32 GiB note: est. slots: 4 EC: None`

Comment: But if you actually look, are there 4 physical slots, and not 8? I ask because I don't see it configured for memory interleaving.

Comment: @heynnema There are 4 physical slots.  This is a desktop board.  I have seen a couple that had the contact pads for 2 more slots that only had 2 physical slots.  This would still show 4 slots with a maximum, but since it was missing slots physically that max could not be reached.  Cheap manufacturers or OEMs have done that with custom boards for themselves.

Comment: OK... no memory interleaving with that MB.

Comment: @heynnema It might, but I remember changing the setting in the BIOS and the system actually sped up.  So, I am not going to argue with the settings.  :)

Comment: Recheck that setting you describe. Maybe it'll force the memory into dual channel mode so it can do interleaving :-)

Comment: It sounds like that old BIOS board is using ganged/unganged as old school terminology for what is called interleaving now. This is a hardware function. And yes, it would make a difference in speed... as long as you have your 4G/8G DIMMs installed properly paired into the correct slots.

Comment: If you check the user manual for your MB, it should tell you which two slots to use first, and which two slots to use second. Pair up the DIMMs.

Comment: @heynnema It is set for Interleave, I just checked it.  It also has the Ganged/Unganged settings.  My board and RAM are running fine.  It is an older AMD board and it does exactly what I need it to do.  I don't need all this new special stuff at all and I despise UEFI.  And why are you trying to fix issues for me that I am not having or asking about?  Please stop!!!

Comment: OK. I'll stop...